# shorttoc and contents appear in headers

Tags: header-footer, etoc, shorttoc

I have a long and complex `book` class document, split in `frontmatter` `mainmatter` and `backmatter`, and using both `shorttoc` for a summary in the beggining and `etoc` for a local TOC of th appendix. With `\pagestyle{headings}`, the headers of the pages located **after** the summary and the appendix's TOC still have "Summary" or "Contents", even on pages containing some text.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\shorttoc{Summary}{0}
\chapter*{Foreword}
\lipsum[1-8]

\mainmatter
\part{ONE}
\chapter{a}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{b}
\lipsum[1-3]

\part{TWO}
\chapter{c}
\lipsum[1-3]

\backmatter
\appendix
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\chapter{Appendix}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{1}\localtableofcontents
\section{one}
\lipsum[1-6]
\section{two}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

On my document, "Summmary" is on page 1, but the word "Summary" still appears in the header of the "foreword", on p.3. Similarly, "contents" appears in the headers of the appendix, on the two last pages, where "appendix" should appear (or "one" or "two" would fit also).

Reading this question ([Contents in heading where I want preface](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87981/contents-in-heading-where-i-want-preface)), I have seen that replacing `chapter*` by `chapter` in the frontmatter solves the problem for page 3.

For the two last pages problem, I have tried a solution proposed here : [Fix "CONTENTS" in header using etoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274169/fix-contents-in-header-using-etoc), by Johannes B, but it didn't solve my problem.

I'm ok to use another extension rather than `etoc` if it does the same work without trouble, but not `minitoc` because it creates too much auxiliary files, considering the big number of chapters I have, and the fact that I only need **one** local TOC for the appendix. A solution using `fancyhdr` could also be good for my purpose, as long as it doesn't need too many re-organizing, because the content of the document is already done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The starred versions of `\chapter` and `\section` don't modify the header, so it keeps showing the last label set. You can set the header yourself using `\markboth`.

```
\chapter*{Foreword}
\markboth{}{}
```

will clear the header, whereas

```
\chapter*{Foreword}
\markboth{Foreword}{Foreword}
```

sets the header to `Foreword`.

Comment: Thank you @gernot ! The problem for the foreword had already disappeared by deleting the star (as the foreword is in `frontmatter`, the chapters are not numbered, so the star was useless), but `\markboth` is very usefull for the Appendix ! I will even be able to make more precise heading, putting one `\markboth` in every section (some are very long) !

Comment: @Malo There is also an optional argument to the unstarred chapter and section commands, to set a short title for header and toc: `\section[Short title]{Long Title}`

Comment: Yes, this is also usefull, but I wis speaking about the length of my sections (nb of pages), not of their title. The organisation that I've chosen makes the whole Appendix get into one `chapter` and not a `Part`, but the Appendix is 400p long. When the document is already written and I'm just making some final corrections, I prefer a solution like adding `markboth` in every section, rather than changing a parameter of the headings only in the Appendix (e.g. with `fancyhdr`). I guess we are more adventurous when beggining a document, and more conservative when it's at the end.